# Image on top of navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can I put an image on top of navigation drawer like Google Play Store or Left sidebar on Google+?

Actually I have my own adapter for the navigation drawer, it put an icon for each element of the list view, and this is the current XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/menuBackground"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I think I must add ImageView in this XML but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found out how to implement this today (if you have not already solved this problem).

Took me hours to **ask the right question**

I think you're looking something like this

[image: Image on top of the listview]

If so, you need to create a xml files to act as a **header** and add to the top of the listview.

so just create a header.xml

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/hatsune" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text Name"
        android:background="#88f3f3f3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#88f3f3f3"
        android:text="Text Point"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Back to your activity lets say **Activity.java**

```
//Header of the listview, go to header.xml to customize
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);

  //addHeaderView is to add custom content into first row
    yourListView.addHeaderView(header);
    yourListView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think I must add ImageView in this XML but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.
```

No, at least in my personal opinion that is not the correct way to implement it. Try to follow a approach like this.

1. Create a layout you want to add to the top of Navigation Drawer.
2. Add that layout as a header in your list using `getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);`

Hope this helps.. :)